# Endpoint nodes list in Kaa

Tags: iot, kaa

I want to get list of endpoints in Kaa, I see many REST functions [here](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API) but all of them need informations like Endpoint Hash Key and ... but I don't know how I can find them.  Anybody can help me how I can do this ? and is there a way for geting event on device discovery in Kaa ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to get endpoint key hash in 3 ways :

1. Get information from Client SDK on your device. Check appropriate documentation of you desirable SDK.
2. Look at Admin UI in [Endpoint profiles menu](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Administration+UI+guide#AdministrationUIguide-Managingendpointprofiles).
3. Get via Admin REST API . 
   Please, check [profiling](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API#AdminRESTAPI-Profiling) section.

I think it will help you to find your desired information.

Answer (score 1):

On [your link](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API#AdminRESTAPI-Getuserauthenticationstatus) for each Rest call, there is the description with the endpoint cresponding to the request. For example:

**Get user authentication status**

- URL : `/kaaAdmin/rest/api/auth/checkAuth`

Same for parameter needed.

If that's not what you are looking for, you might have to explain a little bit more.

Comment: Thank you, I want to get endpoints list with owner user and I don't know for example what is the user_id ? is it tenant user id ? how can I find it ?

Comment: Are you talking about client or server side endpoint ? I'm not familiar enough with the API but i found in the documentation that there are two different endpoints for the Profiling section : http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API#AdminRESTAPI-Profiling